# How to programatically insert lines in csv file based on quantity of specific record

Tags: c#, winforms, csv, datagridview, export-to-csv

I have a program that runs a SQL query and returns data to a datagridview.

[image: DataGridView Example]

I then write the data to a csv file which works great.

[image]

However, I need to add a line in the csv for each item based on the quantity of the record.
The first record (highlighted in blue) has a quantity of 12, so I need to insert 12 lines containing the information from the first record, and so forth down the list.

This is what I would like to show :
[image]

Below is the code that I am using to create the csv file.

```
string strValue = string.Empty;
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells.Count; j++)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dataGridView1[j, i].Value.ToString()))
        {
            if (j > 0)
                strValue = strValue + "," + dataGridView1[j, i].Value.ToString();
            else
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(strValue))
                    strValue = dataGridView1[j, i].Value.ToString();
                else
                    strValue = strValue + Environment.NewLine + dataGridView1[j, i].Value.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}

string strFile = @"\\\\Path_To_CSV\\DynamicsPartsLabels.csv";
if (File.Exists(strFile) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(strValue))
{
    File.WriteAllText(strFile, strValue);
}
```

Is there a way to read the last column in the datagridview (Quantity) and create a line in a csv for each record based on the number in that column?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the code to:

```
 StringBuilder rows = new StringBuilder();
 var row = string.Empty;
 for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
 {
    row = string.Join(",", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>().Select(x => x.Value));
    int.TryParse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Quantity"].Value?.ToString(), out var quantity);
    for (int q = 0; q < quantity; q++)
    {
       rows.AppendLine(row);
    }      
 }
 var strValue = rows.ToString();
```

Comment: Unfortunately that creates a CSV with one record written one time (the last record in the datagrid view) with the quantity field included

Comment: would you be able set a breakpoint inside the for loop to debug and figure out what is happening?

Comment: Change `index++` to `q++`.  That said, I can't see why this isn't producing more records, unless `quantity` is not getting the value out as expected.

Comment: Thanks @OhBeWise, I've edited the post to fix it. not sure how it only writes one line to the csv.